# move all directlabels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using directlabels for the first time today and as this is a new package the documentation is pretty sparse still.  I have created a faceted density plot similar to this data and the labels could all be moved up and slightly right.

If this were mtext I could use `adj` and `padj` to move the text around.  How would I do the same to the labels below.   Move every label slightly up and slightly right?

```
library(directlabels); library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(CO2, aes(x=conc, group=Type))
h <- g + geom_density(aes(colour=Type)) +facet_grid(Treatment~.)
direct.label(h)
```

This is the last bit until I have a figure ready for publication and so help here would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**  ***The `top.bumptwice` doesn't move the text up quite enough.  I would like more control over the move.***

Comment: I can get it close but I used `dlcompare(list(p),list(
     '+dl.move'=list(dl.move("post",0,hjust=-2,vjust=-4), 
     dl.move("pre",0,hjust=-1,vjust=0))))` as demonstrated in the manual and it prints the `+dl.move` at the top of the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the author and you can pass the moves to `direct.labels` as a list:

```
library(ggplot2); library(directlabels)
x <- ggplot(CO2, aes(x=uptake, group=Plant))
y <- x + geom_density(aes(colour=Plant)) + 
    facet_grid(Type~Treatment)+ theme_bw()
y 


my.method1 <- list('top.points',dl.move("Qn1",  hjust=0,vjust=-5) 
)


direct.label(y, my.method1)
```