# direct.label in ggplot (scatterplot) not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I want the direct-label function to position the labels of the datapoints in a way that they do not overlap. However, I'm getting an error that tells me that I need the aes function specifiying the labels. This is odd, as I already have included it.

This is the code I'm using:

```
p<- ggplot(d, aes(x=ILE2, y=TE,label=d$CA)) +
  geom_point(shape=20,size=6,label=d$CA)+
  geom_smooth(method=lm,se=F)+
  scale_colour_hue(l=50)+
  ggtitle("Tasa de Empleo según Índice de Libertad Económica") +
  labs(x="Índice de Libertad Económica",y="Tasa de Empleo") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Arial", color="#666666", face="bold", size=22, hjust=0.5)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "Arial", color="#666666", face="bold", size=22))
direct.label(p,method="smart.grid")
```

This is the output:

[image]

This is the dataset:

```
structure(list(CA = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 
7L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 13L), .Label = c("Andalucía", 
"Aragón", "Asturias", "Balears", "C. La Mancha", "C. Valenciana", 
"C. y León", "Canarias", "Cantabria", "Cataluña", "Extremadura", 
"Galicia", "La Rioja", "Madrid", "Murcia", "Navarra", "País Vasco"
), class = "factor"), CA.excel = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
10L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L), .Label = c("Andalucía", 
"Aragón", "Asturias, Principado de", "Balears, Illes", "Canarias", 
"Cantabria", "Castilla - La Mancha", "Castilla y León", "Cataluña", 
"Comunitat Valenciana", "Extremadura", "Galicia", "Madrid, Comunidad de", 
"Murcia, Región de", "Navarra, Comunidad Foral de", "País Vasco", 
"Rioja, La"), class = "factor"), ILE = c(0.64, 0.45, 0.61, 0.36, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.48, 0.54, 0.5, 0.5, 0.72, 0.53, 0.19, 0.49, 0.43, 
0.46, 0.39), ILE2 = c(0.36, 0.55, 0.39, 0.64, 0.6, 0.6, 0.52, 
0.46, 0.5, 0.5, 0.28, 0.48, 0.81, 0.51, 0.58, 0.54, 0.61), TE = c(39.04, 
47.6, 40.61, 48.82, 44.65, 43.06, 45.77, 41.85, 43.49, 49.76, 
38.38, 41.82, 53.08, 43.4, 49.49, 47.98, 48.83), migdest = c(21774L, 
5511L, 3147L, 9333L, 17187L, 7568L, 2689L, 12547L, 8701L, 19727L, 
3878L, 6147L, 38182L, 6678L, 3024L, 7363L, 1736L), Poblacion = c(8399618L, 
1326403L, 1049875L, 1124972L, 4939674L, 2126144L, 585359L, 2062767L, 
2478079L, 7396991L, 1091623L, 2734656L, 6385298L, 1463773L, 636402L, 
2165100L, 313569L), MigraPob = c(0.002592261, 0.004154845, 0.002997501, 
0.008296203, 0.003479379, 0.003559496, 0.004593765, 0.006082607, 
0.003511188, 0.002666895, 0.003552507, 0.002247815, 0.005979674, 
0.004562182, 0.004751713, 0.003400767, 0.005536262), Ocupados = structure(c(3L, 
12L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 14L, 5L, 13L, 16L, 7L, 8L, 17L, 4L, 11L, 6L, 
15L, 2L), .Label = c("1.836.300", "126.900", "2.683.700", "2.786.600", 
"226.300", "258.200", "3.023.200", "350.100", "371.800", "455.900", 
"513.400", "524.500", "707.000", "771.500", "870.300", "913.300", 
"987.500"), class = "factor"), Activos = structure(c(11L, 15L, 
12L, 14L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 17L, 3L, 9L, 13L, 4L, 8L, 16L, 10L, 1L, 
5L), .Label = c("1.041.500,00", "1.115.000,00", "1.147.000,00", 
"1.263.200,00", "153.900,00", "2.425.100,00", "277.900,00", "3.389.400,00", 
"3.781.300,00", "306.100,00", "4.042.900,00", "458.900,00", "501.800,00", 
"586.600,00", "644.300,00", "700.300,00", "991.500,00"), class = "factor"), 
    Tocup = c(0.664, 0.814, 0.81, 0.777, 0.757, 0.692, 0.814, 
    0.713, 0.796, 0.8, 0.698, 0.782, 0.822, 0.733, 0.844, 0.836, 
    0.825), Paro = c(0.336, 0.186, 0.19, 0.223, 0.243, 0.308, 
    0.186, 0.287, 0.204, 0.2, 0.302, 0.218, 0.178, 0.267, 0.156, 
    0.164, 0.175), X..Emp.disueltas14 = structure(c(9L, 16L, 
    12L, 15L, 17L, 8L, 14L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 11L, 2L, 13L, 10L, 5L, 
    3L, 6L), .Label = c("1.102", "1.529", "1.544", "1.953", "160", 
    "196", "2.465", "260", "3.172", "349", "362", "467", "5.147", 
    "552", "833", "846", "915"), class = "factor"), EmpD1000h = c(0.3776, 
    0.6378, 0.4448, 0.7405, 0.1852, 0.1223, 0.943, 0.5342, 0.9947, 
    0.264, 0.3316, 0.5591, 0.8061, 0.2384, 0.2514, 0.7131, 0.6251
    ), EmpCreadas = c(15541L, 1933L, 1364L, 2887L, 11206L, 3486L, 
    819L, 2812L, 3000L, 17664L, 1186L, 4266L, 20268L, 2732L, 
    905L, 3447L, 448L), TasaEmpC = c(1.850203188, 1.45732481, 
    1.299202286, 2.566286094, 2.26857076, 1.639587911, 1.399141382, 
    1.363217465, 1.210615158, 2.387998039, 1.086455672, 1.559976831, 
    3.174166656, 1.866409614, 1.422057127, 1.592074269, 1.42871266
    ), RentaMediaHogar = c(21332L, 29120L, 25623L, 26923L, 22392L, 
    21539L, 23905L, 22271L, 24587L, 30407L, 19364L, 26001L, 31587L, 
    21269L, 33047L, 34240L, 26666L), GananciaMediaTrab = c(20782.03, 
    22054.85, 21994.99, 20776.29, 19167.93, 20052.12, 20440.56, 
    20630.07, 24253.73, 20878.02, 19129.72, 19824.66, 26215.36, 
    20449.83, 23836.93, 26915.07, 20628.81)), .Names = c("CA", 
"CA.excel", "ILE", "ILE2", "TE", "migdest", "Poblacion", "MigraPob", 
"Ocupados", "Activos", "Tocup", "Paro", "X..Emp.disueltas14", 
"EmpD1000h", "EmpCreadas", "TasaEmpC", "RentaMediaHogar", "GananciaMediaTrab"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`directlabels` was never really intended for labelling points in a scatterplot. A lot of the time, `directlabels` does a reasonable job, but the new package `ggrepel` might be better suited to the labelling of points in scatterplots. (requires `ggplot2` v2.0.0)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

p <- ggplot(d, aes(x = ILE2, y = TE, label = CA)) +
  geom_point(shape = 20, size = 5) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = F) +
  scale_colour_hue(l = 50) +
  ggtitle("Tasa de Empleo según Índice de Libertad Económica") +
  labs(x = "Índice de Libertad Económica", y = "Tasa de Empleo") 

p +  geom_text_repel(aes(label = CA), segment.color = "black",
                 box.padding = unit(0.45, "lines"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With your code, I was getting the following error:

```
     Error in direct.label.ggplot(p, method = "smart.grid") : 
       Need colour aesthetic to infer default direct labels.
```

So, I added the colour aesthetic like so:

```
p<- ggplot(d, aes(x=ILE2, y=TE, col=CA)) +
  geom_point(shape=20,size=6) +
  geom_smooth(method=lm,se=F, aes(group=1))+
  scale_colour_hue(l=50)+
  ggtitle("Tasa de Empleo según Índice de Libertad Económica") +
  labs(x="Índice de Libertad Económica",y="Tasa de Empleo") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Arial", color="#666666", face="bold", size=22, hjust=0.5)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "Arial", color="#666666", face="bold", size=22))
```

I could use `direct.label` now,

```
direct.label(p,method="smart.grid")
```

The output:

[image]

However, if you want points to be black and have no color, you could use geom_dl from directlabels 2.0 like so,

```
p<- ggplot(d, aes(x=ILE2, y=TE)) +
  geom_point(shape=20,size=6) + geom_dl(aes(label=d$CA), method="smart.grid")+ 
  geom_smooth(method=lm,se=F)+
  scale_colour_hue(l=50)+
  ggtitle("Tasa de Empleo según Índice de Libertad Económica") +
  labs(x="Índice de Libertad Económica",y="Tasa de Empleo") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Arial", color="#666666", face="bold", size=22, hjust=0.5)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "Arial", color="#666666", face="bold", size=22))
```

The output: [image]

Note that the purpose of direct.labels is to hide color legends. (Description of direct.label : "Add direct labels to a plot, and hide the color legend. Modern plotting packages like lattice and ggplot2 show automatic legends based on the variable specified for color, but these legends can be confusing if there are too many colors. Direct labels are a useful and clear alternative to a confusing legend in many common plots.")

If a plot does not have a color legend (which is the case with your code), `direct.label` is no use. I think you should go with `geom_dl` since the way you want to present your data, it does not need color legends.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm getting the following error when I execute your code: Error: 'ggproto' is not an exported object from 'namespace:ggplot2' Any idea?

Comment: I am not sure why that is. It maybe due to difference in version of R we are using. What version of R and directlabels do you have?

Comment: Ok! Now it works, but this is not exactly the result I was expecting, because there are labels that are not close to its point (redindering them useless). For example, Cantabria, Andalucia and C. y Leon are really far from their points. Any idea on how to address this?

Comment: You can move individual labels using `dl.move`. Questions on that have been answered. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695397/move-all-directlabels) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390435/directlabels-shift-label-when-using-geom-dl)